# Selenium: how do I click show button, scrape hrefs, then click show button again?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Link to the page I am trying to scrape:

https://www.nytimes.com/reviews/dining

Because this page has a "show more" button, I needed Selenium to automatically click the "show more" button iteratively, and then somehow use Beautiful soup to harvest the links to each individual restaurant review on the page. In the photo below, the link I want to harvest is within the https://...onigiri.html">.

[image]

Code so far:

```
url = "https://www.nytimes.com/reviews/dining"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

for i in range(1):
  button = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button")
  button.click()
```

How do I use WebDriverWait and BeautifulSoup [BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')] to complete this task?

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part you're struggling with? You probably don't need BeautifulSoup for this, by the way.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look at other examples using WebDriverWait? And what links are you trying to scrape? You can most likely just use Selenium to get them and don't need BeautifulSoup at all.

Comment: @AMC yup! I've just included a photo in my problem to further clarify which links I am trying to scrape.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've tried looking at WebDriverWait documentation — there are things like find_element_by_tag_name, x_path, css_selector, but I'm not quite sure how to apply the examples that I've found around the internet to my particular problem just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lazy loading application.To click on the `Show More` button you need to use `infinite` loop and `scroll down` the page to look for and then `click` and wait for some time to load the page and then store the value in the `list`.Verify the list before and after if it matches then break from infinite loop.

**Code**:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.nytimes.com/reviews/dining")
#To accept the coockie click on that
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Accept']"))).click()
listhref=[]

while(True):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.css-gg4vpm")))
    lenlistbefore=len(listhref)
    for ele in elements:
        if ele.get_attribute("href") in listhref:
            continue
        else:
            listhref.append(ele.get_attribute("href"))

    lenlistafter = len(listhref)

    if lenlistbefore==lenlistafter:
        break

    button=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Show More']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
    time.sleep(2)
print(len(listhref))
print(listhref)
```

**Note**:- I am getting list count `499`

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked with the adjustment to this line: "WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Accept']"))).click()
listhref=[]" — I essentially just changed the XPATH to "//button[text()='Show More']", which was an easy and convenient fix.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.nytimes.com/reviews/dining press F12 and then press Ctrl+Shift+C to get element **Show More**, then as I showed in picture get your xpath of element:

[image]

In order to find xpath please look at:

https://www.techbeamers.com/locate-elements-selenium-python/#locate-element-by-xpath

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def executeTest():
    global driver
    driver.get('https://www.nytimes.com/reviews/dining')
    time.sleep(7)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('Your_Xpath')
    element.click()
    time.sleep(3)

def startWebDriver():
    global driver
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    startWebDriver()
    executeTest()
    driver.quit()
```